# Is there a PDF reader with reading mode like adobe does in its mobile app?

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf

I have a visual impairance. Hence, I have to zoom in a lot to be able to read. As a result, lines don't fit the screen anymore and I have to go left and right all the time.

Adobe acrobat reader does have reading mode feature that divides the line no matter how much you zoom in. Yet, to best of my knowledge, adobe doesn't support linux. Also I am not sure if it has the same feature for the computer.

So, is there any PDF reader that has that feature?